# How to write output files with variable names with path join

Tags: python

I'm trying to save file name , my filename should be like this "doc00012dsadfile5.jpg"

```
filename = "doc00012dsad.pdf"
mypath = "/desktop/myfolder/"
_path = os.path.join(mypath,"images")
num = 5
#filename.split(".pdf",1)[0] 
os.path.join(_path, file%d.jpg" % num), xx)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
filename = "doc00012dsad.pdf"
mypath = "/desktop/myfolder/"
_path = os.path.join(mypath,"images")
num = 5
#filename.split(".pdf",1)[0] 
os.path.join(_path, "file{}.jpg".format(num), xx)
```

I don't know what xx is, but I have just put it there because it was in your code

Answer (score 0):

Just inject them before joining to avoid confusions

```
import os
filename = "doc00012dsad.pdf"
mypath = "/desktop/myfolder/"
_path = os.path.join(mypath,"images")
num = 5
file ="file"
f_name = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]

filename = f'{f_name}{file}{num}.jpg'

final = os.path.join(_path,filename)
```

Final path

```
/desktop/myfolder/images/doc00012dsadfile5.jpg
```